# JavaScript onClick event - HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I'm learning JavaScript and recently I have been experimenting with Mouse events, trying to understand how they work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mouse Events Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleEvent(oEvent) {
            var oTextbox = document.getElementById("txt1");
            oTextbox.value += "\n" + oEvent.type;

            if(oEvent.type=="click")
            {
            var iScreenX = oEvent.screenX;
            var iScreenY = oEvent.screenY;
            var b = "Clicked at "+iScreenX+" , "+iScreenY;

            alert(b);
            }
        }
        function handleEvent1(oEvent) {
            // alert("Left Window");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Use your mouse to click and double click the red square</p>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red"
        onmouseover="handleEvent(event)"
        onmouseout="handleEvent1(event)"
        onmousedown="handleEvent(event)"
        onmouseup="handleEvent(event)"
        onclick="handleEvent(event)"
        ondblclick="handleEvent(event)" id="div1"></div>
    <p><textarea id="txt1" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea></p>
</body>
```

this is the code I have been trying to understand. Can anyone help me to Create a HTML table that upon clicking in a cell of the table user is told cell he is clicking in?
been stuck on it for time, thanks for help.

Comment: There's no table in your HTML

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
            tableText(this);
        };
    }
}

function tableText(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
}
```

is an example of what you could do.  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8A37s/5/)

Comment: I upvoted you but I think your answer can be improved. http://jsfiddle.net/8A37s/7/.

Comment: @robbmj That's a good idea, but I don't think the OP has table cells that are named like that

Comment: @user2169914 happy to help, please remember to upvote and accept Man of Snow's answer.

Comment: For getting column and row indexes in the onClick function, you must declare _i_ & _j_ variables with **let** instead of _var_;

Answer (score 5):

Just insert `onclick` into each `<td>` of the table and if the cell's name were example, you could do something similar to this:

```
<td onclick="alert('You are clicking on the cell EXAMPLE')">
```

Comment: perfectly reduced to the max!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using getElementById, we could use .querySelectorAll to retrieve all the table dimensions AKA cells. After which, we can execute a single loop (Although please note that in the back end of JS, there will still be a loop executed to retrieve table cells.). First, let's create the action to be carried out upon clicking a cell:

```
function tableText() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Let's retrieve all the cells with querySelectorAll method:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td")
```

Place the event listener to each and every cell:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", tableText)
}
```

> Complete code:

```
function tableText() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}

var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td")

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
  cells[i].addEventListener("click", tableText)
}
```