# How to click an element of a table row that has a column with specific text?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a table with multiple rows. I need to be able to find a column with specific text and then click that row's delete button.

I am able to find the row by its userName, but when I try to say "click its delete button", it complains that it can't find the delete button's element.

Table's code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle">77716d61-32ea-4bf3-a2bd-e48645d049ee</td>
        <td class="align-middle">asdf</td>
        <td class="align-middle">asdf@asdf.com</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/Identity/UserDelete/77716d61-32ea-4bf3-a2bd-e48645d049ee"><span class="oi oi-x"></span></a>
        </td>
</tbody>
```

I've tried:

```
.click(Selector('tbody').find('td').withText(name).find('.btn.btn-danger'))
```

and:

```
.click(Selector('tbody').find('td').withText(name).find('td').find('a').find('.btn.btn-danger'))
```

as well as played with sibling and child, but I don't quite understand those.

Expected: The delete button is clicked for that table's row.

Actual: 
After it finds the column with the UserName, it doesn't want to keep going through the row to click the delete button.

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

Â   | Selector('tbody')
Â   |   .find('td')
Â   |   .withText('Automationieweg')
Â > |   .find('td')
Â   |   .find('a')
Â   |   .find('.btn.btn-danger')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033368/javascript-onclick-event-html-table

Answer (score 2):

I researched .sibling for testcafe more closely and came up with this solution:

```
.click(Selector('tbody').find('td').withText(name).sibling('td').find('a').nth(1))
```

This finds the row with the name I'm looking for, gets the sibling element of 'td' from the parent 'tr' that has an 'a' child and clicks the second one in the row (which is the delete button.)

Answer (score 1):

when you get your username element, you have to find common parent element with delete button and find it in parent. this is very easy in javascript